# DevExpress: How to create click event handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, devexpress

In my app I have a table with some rows. When I press on a '+' next to row, I need to expand it and display another table. How can I add an event handler to code for this '+'? When I press twice on it, I create event handler for click event for all row and I need it only for a '+' button.

[image]

This is what it generates:

```
private void GridCandidates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
}
```

This is how I added '+':

```
[NotMapped]
public List<CandidateStatusLog> CandidateStatusesLog { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the events related to the GridControl are actually fired by the view, not the control. For instance, in this case you can handle the GridView's [MasterRowExpanding](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.MasterRowExpanding) event which is fired as the [+] is clicked and a detail table is about to be displayed.

If you want to dynamically change the details view at runtime, I would suggest reviewing the [Load Details Dynamically by Handling Events](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/732/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/master-detail/working-with-master-detail-relationships-in-code#events) documentation as well.

The GridControl should automatically be able to generate a detail view if the parent object has a collection property such as a List like you're doing. See the [Binding to Objects with Collection Properties](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/732/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/master-detail/working-with-master-detail-relationships-in-code#collections) for information about this.